# POST URL is missing handler query string in Razor Page

Tags: asp.net, post, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm having an issue where my form submission url does not have a query string which points to the handler in the Code Behind. As a result I'm getting a 400 (bad request) error.

The request URL looks like this: 
`http://localhost:60900/EventRename`

When it should look like this:
`http://localhost:60900/EventRename?handler=RenameEvent`

Here's the .cshtml

```
<form asp-page-handler="RenameEvent" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RenameDataSource"></label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RenameDataSource, Model.DataSources, "-- select data source --")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RenameTempEvent"></label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RenameTempEvent, Model.RenameTempEvents, "-- select event type --")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="NewName"></label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.NewName, Model.EventTypes, "-- select event type --")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Start Renaming</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

It might be related, but I've also noticed that the form data is missing the '__RequestVerificationToken', which should be included by default in Razor pages?

To clarify, I'm not expecting to see the data from the form in the URL. I'm expecting to see a handler reference so the Razor Code Behind knows which method to run when the form is submitted. See this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/#multiple-handlers-per-page
`the URL path that submits to OnPostJoinListAsync is http://localhost:5000/Customers/CreateFATH?handler=JoinList`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the tag helpers, possibly because you don't have a _ViewImports.cshtml file

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ActionName, ControllerName, new { handler = "value of your handler" }, FormMethod.Post))
```

Now you can submit the form it will give you the value for the same.

Answer (score -2):

your form method is post try to use get if you want to see the data string in url.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: I'm not expecting to see the form data, but the post request will go to a specific URL specified by the 'asp-page-handler'. See the bottom of this section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/#multiple-handlers-per-page